# How can I make the slide move left only on the first click and deny it from moving left on the first click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

My slide area scrolls right when the left button is clicked however there is nothing there and so is there a way to lock the first click so that it can only be scrolled left when it has been scrolled right first? Is there also a way to lock the scroll after its reached the last div?

```js
var $slider = $("#recent-container")

$("#right-button").click(function() {
  $slider.css("left", "-=932px")
});

$("#left-button").click(function() {
  $slider.css("left", "+=932px")
});
```

```css
/*----------Recent Projects----------*/

#recent-title {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'calibri light';
  border-bottom: #d8d8d8 solid 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.thmbnl-name {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'calibri light';
  text-align: center;
}

#recent {
  text-align: center;
  border: #d8d8d8 solid 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 950px;
  height: 330px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#recent #recent-container {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 10px;
}

#recent #recent-container .thmbnl-recent {
  display: inline-block;
}

.thmbnl-recent {
  padding: 19.5px;
}

.thmbnl-recent:hover {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  transition: background-color ease 1s;
}

#right-button {
  font-family: 'calibri';
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 35px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 37.5%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
}

#left-button {
  font-family: 'calibri';
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 35px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 37.5%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div id="recent">
  <h2 id="recent-title">Recent Projects</h2>
  <div id="recent-container">
    <div class="thmbnl-recent">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
      <h1 class="thmbnl-name">Sample</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="thmbnl-recent">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
      <h1 class="thmbnl-name">Sample</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="thmbnl-recent">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
      <h1 class="thmbnl-name">Sample</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="thmbnl-recent">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
      <h1 class="thmbnl-name">Sample</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="thmbnl-recent">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
      <h1 class="thmbnl-name">Sample</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="thmbnl-recent">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
      <h1 class="thmbnl-name">Sample</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="thmbnl-recent">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
      <h1 class="thmbnl-name">Sample</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="thmbnl-recent">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x190">
      <h1 class="thmbnl-name">Sample</h1>
    </div>

  </div>

  <p id="right-button">></p>
  <p id="left-button">
    <</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change the button functions to only change the CSS if `recent-container` is not at the end. For example, for the right button:

```
  var $slider = $("#recent-container");
  $("#right-button").click(function() {
    if ($slider.position().left + $slider.width() > 0) $slider.css("left", "-=932px");
  });

  $("#left-button").click(function() {
    if ($slider.position().left < 0) $slider.css("left", "+=932px");
  });
```

Comment: I tried your code but unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: Check out my answer now. I tried it and it works for me.

Comment: For sure, glad I can help!